# String.intern() returning different values in a JDBC driver

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Whilst I was trying to make a fake JDBC driver to test a secure classloader I found an odd behaviour with the following code:

```
val stringClass = java.lang.String::class.java
val intern = stringClass.getMethod("intern")
val pooledString = intern.invoke("Hello World") as String
val valueField = stringClass.getDeclaredField("value")
valueField.isAccessible = true
val pooledValue = valueField.get(pooledString) as ByteArray
println(
        """|----------------------------------------
           | String: ${System.identityHashCode(stringClass)}
           | Thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}
           | Pooled: ${System.identityHashCode(pooledString)}
           | Internal: ${System.identityHashCode(pooledValue)}
           |----------------------------------------""".trimMargin()
)
for (index in pooledValue.indices) {
    pooledValue[index] = 'X'.toByte()
}
```

Running the above code from a JDBC driver's companion object gives this:

```
String: 349885916
Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
Pooled: 718231523
Internal: 1349414238
```

but running the same code from a method of the test class before loading the JDBC driver (during the same execution of the program) gives this:

```
String: 349885916
Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
Pooled: 1635756693
Internal: 504527234
```

I would have thought that getting the interned version of the string should have given the same string in both cases, but it seems that even within the same run of the program the 2 locations give different values for String.intern, which conflicts with the javadoc which says:

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
>   string equal to this **String** object as determined by
>   the **equals(Object)** method, then the string from the pool is
>   returned. Otherwise, this **String** object is added to the
>   pool and a reference to this **String** object is returned.

Is this to be expected, and if so why is it that the values differ?

Comment: Just to be sure that I get you correctly… you are hacking into the string internals, overwriting the string’s array and then, you are surprised that the next lookup into the string pool does not find this string?

Comment: I am surprised that in 2 situations on the same thread String.intern() gives back different objects.

Comment: Performing a lookup implies not only hashing, but comparing the actual content, you even cited “*as determined by the equals(Object) method*”. You are manipulating that content, creating an inconsistent state, leading to inconsistent behavior. What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the reference has been garbage collected. The contract says that if you get the same string twice and compare the returned strings they will be equal. However, if you get a string, release the reference (making the pooled string available for gc) and then get a similar string again, nothing guarantees that it will still be pooled. You will get a new pooled string instead and that has a different identityHashCode.

Keep a reference to pooledString so that it cannot be garbage collected and see what happens!

Comment: I tried keeping a reference in the companion object of the JDBC driver, but the behaviour didn't change

Comment: Please do this test. When you first run the test snippet, store pooledString in s (saved somewhere). Then, when you run the snippet the second time, print the hash code for s as well as the hash code for the new pooledString as well as the boolean pooledString == s. What happens?

Comment: I am printing the System identity codes, do you want me to repeat in the 2 environments also?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. I thought you were starting a program that printed the codes, kept a reference to pooledString somewhere so it couldn't be gc:d and then printed the codes again with another result? If so, print the code for the saved object as well in both places plus the equality check between saved and interned. If you are running the program twice different identity codes between runs are normal.

Comment: Same run of the program,1 is from in a JDBC driver, the other is in the main class, the main class one gets the expected one (modifies the string used later), whereas in the JDBC driver the returned String is different to the expected one.